# How to merge two product collections in Magento2

Tags: configurable-product, product-collection, related-products, up-sells

I need help because I need to combine data from two subjects into one.
I have configurable products. I want to download related and upsell products from "parent" and "child".
In Laravel it would look something like this:

```
$result = $childrenProducts->merge($parentPorducts);
```

Does anyone have an idea how to do it in Magento2?

Comment: You need to create different collection and get them individual where you want to use tha one.

Comment: I;m sorry, butI don't understand your answer.

Comment: why you want to combine the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new collection from two product collections by extracting the product IDs

for

```
$productCollection1
$productCollection2
```

get the product ids from both collections and merge into one array

```
$merged_ids = array_merge($productCollection1->getAllIds(), $productCollection2->getAllIds());
```

Create a new collection using the product ids

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $merged_ids));
```

Comment: If we have setPageSize in our productCollection then this will not work, as getAllIds() return all the Ids in the collection irrepective of the setPageSize function.

Answer (score 0):

Less resource intensive

```
    /**
     * Merge product and child collections.
     *
     * @param ProductCollection $productCollection
     * @param ProductCollection $childCollection
     * @return ProductCollection
     */
    private function mergeCollections(ProductCollection $productCollection, ProductCollection $childCollection): ProductCollection
    {
        foreach ($childCollection as $childProduct) {
            $productCollection->addItem($childProduct);
        }

        return $productCollection;
    }
```